# Make drop down options appear as buttons using CSS

Tags: html, css, button, drop-down-menu

Say I have the follwing HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>Item A</option>
    <option>Item B</option>
    <option>Item C</option>
</select>
```

Obviously, this will render a dropdown with three items in it. I would like these options to appear as buttons, rather than a drop down list - so it would look like the HTML was as such:

```
<button>Item A</button>
<button>Item B</button>
<button>Item B</button>
```

However, I don't want to change the HTML in order to accomplish this. How can I make this drop down selector appear as a column of buttons instead, using only CSS?

Note: The solution needs to work in Internet Explorer 8

Answer (score -1):

use coding below:

```
<div><button>Item A</button></div>
<div><button>Item B</button></div>
<div><button>Item B</button></div>
```

you can use css styles

```
<style>
button{display:block;}    
</style>
```

Comment: *"I don't want to change the HTML in order to accomplish this"*

Comment: if you want to use css then you can use below code.  button{display:block;}